# Python: Can you read mouseover text from windows?

Tags: python, cursor, project

The picture will help, see the hover text in the bottom right as I hover my mouse over the wifi icon. Is there a way in python to read the hover text as I move my mouse to different icons with different hover text? Help would be greatly appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiiFA.png

Answer (score -1):

```html
# 导入selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# selenium中的actionchains的方法
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver.get('http://speed.qq.com/cp/a20170711marketing/index.htm')
driver.maximize_window()
# 识别需要悬停的元素  
ele = driver.find_element_by_link_text('车神回归 极品必得')
# 鼠标移到悬停元素上  
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ele).perform()
```

Using this code